# MySQL database design confusion | permissions

Tags: php, mysql, database, erd

I'm doing a web application for personal purposes that will allow the users and organizations {org} to post {topics}. 
Web app purpose is to allow organizations to post research request for those who are interested for a prize, others can participate to win a prize.

Other users should be able to comment or post a comment(upload) (will be a pdf submission for a research contest)

Now, I'created this erd and database
[image: ERD for initial testing]

Now inside topics.php I've created tabs, [details, submission]

The submission = two stages 
stage one - upload research proposal pdf 
once rated by the owner > pass 
the id is saved in an array called pass

stage two = upload research final draft pdf for rating 
in this stage only those who passed should be able to post in this area, others watch only.

once a user clicks on submission tab, the user will be able to upload a file, once the topic owner allows him to go to the second stage, which is to upload final submission, the user can access another tab to submit final pdf

Now, I'm confused here, how am I going to store the id of those who are qualified to post final submission?

Any comments or guidance, please.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you'll probably want to create a topics_permissions table, which has a topic_id (referencing your topics table) and a user_id (from your users table); when the topic owner approves a user to upload a final submission, just add a row to the topics_permissions table.

Does that help?

Comment: Do you mean a new relationship must be created between the two tables Topics and Users and the relationship is *:* ?

Comment: BTW, thank you for your comment, your suggestion kind of set me away from my confusion or panic circle that I had :\

Comment: Glad I could help :) Yeah, if what you're trying to do is say "this set of users can post to this topic", I'm suggesting you just represent that as a table. You might want to look at some common role-based authentication systems; CanCan is a popular one for rails, but I'm not familiar with the php options. You may not need anything that complex, but just reading how they work might give you some ideas. Good luck!